Reproducing the accumulated interest computed by the bank.
I have a Lifetime ISA saving with a 4.4% AER. The current balance is £1,178.04. The website shows that the today's interest is £0.1042.
(As far as I know) The formula is:
$= \frac{(principal * interest rate)}{365}$
$= \frac{1,178.04*0.044}{365} = 0.1420$
Missing for 4 pennies daily.
Same problem with a Hungarian Forint. I have 100,111.21 HUF with 7.00 % APY shows the today's interest is 18.546 HUF.
$= \frac{100,111.21*0.07}{365} = 19.1994$
Missing 0.65 HUF daily.
What am I missing?

The formula you show is for simple interest. See Wikipedia: Compound interest or other online resources for more detail.
